# Retrieve image and display in picturebox with image path stored in database c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have Image Paths stored in my database under a column called Image in the format of `Images\ac.jpg` The path is already stored in a textbox called `txtImage.Text`. I am trying to display it in a picturebox control but I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Images\ac.jpg

```
pbImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(txtImage.Text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the full path to your image to the `PictureBox`. The relative path `Images\ac.jpg` will not work. You need an absolute path like `C:\Images\ac.jpg`

If your Images folder is where your executable is you can try creating the absolute path as shown below

```
string absolutePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"Images\ac.jpg");

pbCoffeeImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(absolutePath);
```

If you are going to allow the user to input the image path, I would recommend you use the `FileDialog` control to make sure the path is valid and an absolute path.

Comment: I have changed it to the full path in the database and it has worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`Images\ac.jpg` is a relative path which is resolved relative to the current working path of your application. The error tells you, that at this location (`workingPath\Images\ac.jpg`) no file exists.
I'd convert it to an absolute path, by adding the path to your Images-folder at the beginning.